# Why isn't React navigation loading new pages?

Tags: reactjs, routes, switch-statement, router

I'm trying to build a react app but the navigation doesn't seem to be working properly. When I load the page it's showing the Navbar with "Tweets" and "Create Tweet", but clicking on them isn't loading the page. I was using an older tutorial with <Switch and I'm trying to update it to Routes>.

I've been working on this all day and can't seem to figure it out. Any idea what I've done wrong?

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, 
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { TweetList } from './TweetList';
import { CreateTweet } from './CreateTweet';

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar bg-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="navbar-item">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Tweets</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="navbar-item">
              <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Tweet</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={TweetList} />
          <Route path="/create" element={CreateTweet} />
        </Routes>

      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TweetList.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
   
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="mt-3">
        <h3>Tweet List</h3>
        <table className="table table-striped mt-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Text</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CreateTweet:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const CreateTweet = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="mt-3">
                <h3>Create Tweet Item</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "twitter-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.27.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit 1: This is a repo of the files I'm working on:
https://github.com/adam-weiler/twitter-clone

Edit 2:
By changing these 2 lines in App.js it seems to be working now:

Doesn't work:

```
<Route path="/" element={TweetList} />
<Route path="/create" element={CreateTweet} />
```

Working:

```
<Route path="/" element={<TweetList />} />
<Route path="/create" element={<CreateTweet />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you forgot to wrap the `Routes` element inside the `Router`, which you imported, but not added to the returned jsx.
Wrapping the div inside `<Router>...</Router>` should fix the routing issue.

Second of all you pass to the `Route.element` prop a component not an element,  I suggest using either the `Route.component` prop or `Route.render` which expects a function that returns an element.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick answer! I added what seems to be working at the end of the post. The <BrowserRouter> is actually used on index.js and wraps around <App />. Is it better to use in App.js instead?

Comment: It's up to you how you structure your application as React is pretty un-opinionated. For example, I would create a `Providers.tsx` component or hoc which I would wrap my `<App/>` with, as `BrowserRouter` is just a routing provider.